# ref counts can't go to zero here: stable=0 unstable=0

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider

```
    // Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ref counts can't go to zero here: stable=0 unstable=0
//  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1628)
//  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
//  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.refContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3601)
//  at android.app.ActivityThread.releaseProvider(ActivityThread.java:4950)
//  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.releaseUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2025)
//  at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1157)
//  at android.content.Contenter code hereentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:944)
//  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:664)
//  at com.android.music.MusicUtils.getArtwork(MusicUtils.java:1239)
//  at com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$NotificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(MediaPlaybackService.java:1809)
//  at com.android.music.MediaPlaybackService$NotificationAsyncTask.doInBackground(MediaPlaybackService.java:1805)
//  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
//  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
//  ... 4 more
//
```

That is my log of after run monkey test.It occur a crash caused by  ref counts can't go to zero here: stable=0 unstable=0 .Who knows the reason for this mistake?